# dataset cannot be loaded although data() lists it

Tags: r

We have [an R library](https://github.com/HISKP-LQCD/hadron) which has the dataset `plaq.sample` in the file `data/plaq.sample.Rdata`. One of the examples of a library function uses it. The example works just fine on my laptop (R 3.5.1), my colleagues laptop (R 3.1.3 and 3.4.4) but it fails on Travis CI (R 3.5.1 as well). The output is the following:

```
> data(plaq.sample)
Warning in data(plaq.sample) : data set ‘plaq.sample’ not found
> plaq.boot <- bootstrap.analysis(plaq.sample, pl=TRUE)
Error in bootstrap.analysis(plaq.sample, pl = TRUE) : 
  object 'plaq.sample' not found
Execution halted
```

This is bewildering. I have called `data()` at the beginning of the example and the output clearly states that this dataset is available:

```
Data sets in package ‘hadron’:

correlatormatrix        
plaq.sample             Sample plaquette time series
pscor.sample            
samplecf                Sample cf data
```

We are lost and do not understand why the `R CMD check .` does work on our laptops but not on Travis CI. What could be the issue for not finding the dataset?

Comment: Did you load the *package* before trying to load the data? Otherwise specify the package when loading the data: `data(plaq.sample, package = 'hadron')` (unrelated, but since I’m already commenting: avoid dots in names, use underscores instead; dots make it confusing when working with S3 name lookup).

Comment: It is an example for a function of that library, so the library should be loaded in this example. The `bootstrap.analysis` function is also part of the library and seemingly available. As `data()` shows the datasets of the loaded packages and it is listed there, I would say that the package is loaded. — dots: I am fully aware, but this is legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read a warning about the hidden file `.Rdata` which was present in the checking. I have added `.Rdata` to the `.Rbuildignore` file to exclude it. However, this file interprets each line as a regular expression, therefore also including `data/plaq.sample.Rdata`. Removing this line makes the dataset available again.